# How can I find the image name from the image ID in OpenStack?

Tags: openstack

E.g. ami-00000073 is used as the image ID. How can find the image name associated to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear.  Each image in OpenStack has:

- an integer ID (used as a database key but otherwise generally not visible),
- a 36-character UUID, like `95e52709-0990-4f52-b192-2ba2c0fa6f7f`
- a display name

Since your example is neither an integer nor a UUID, it must *be* the display name.  If you can provide more information (for example, "when I run this command I see this output; how do I convert that output into this other information I need", showing both the output of the commands you type), we can provide a better answer.

Generally, you can use either the `nova image-*` commands for interacting with images or the `glance` command.  To see a list of available images using `nova`:

```
nova image-list
```

Or using `glance`:

```
glance index
```

You can get detailed information about a particular image using `nova image-show` or `glance show`, which will give you something like this:

```
$ glance show f66ea2c4-21f2-4a5e-ad8f-9af6d5f8b9d1
URI: http://10.1.1.61:9292/v1/images/f66ea2c4-21f2-4a5e-ad8f-9af6d5f8b9d1
Id: f66ea2c4-21f2-4a5e-ad8f-9af6d5f8b9d1
Public: Yes
Protected: No
Name: CentOS 6 x86_64
Status: active
Size: 1073741824
Disk format: raw
Container format: bare
Minimum Ram Required (MB): 0
Minimum Disk Required (GB): 0
Owner: a1af2e48a97549b787959618998a52f7
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is the AMI ID, which is separate from the Glance image ID, which is a standard-format UUID in newer versions of OpenStack.

The AMI ID is provided for compatibility with cloud-init or other tooling when using the EC2 compatibility layer. It is accessed from inside the instance by querying http://169.154.169.154/latest/meta-data/ami-id or extracting the `ami-id` property from `metadata.json` on the config drive.

`nova.api.ec2.ec2utils` provides a method called `image_ec2_id`:

```
def image_ec2_id(image_id, image_type='ami'):
    """Returns image ec2_id using id and three letter type."""
    template = image_type + '-%08x'
    try:
        return id_to_ec2_id(image_id, template=template)
    except ValueError:
        #TODO(wwolf): once we have ec2_id -> glance_id mapping
        # in place, this wont be necessary
        return "ami-00000000"
```

So, the AMI ID is just a hex-encoded version of the numeric S3 image ID (not the UUID) of the Glance image. As far as I know, this value is not exposed through any of the command-line tools or server APIs, and needs to be queried through your database directly. These numeric mappings are stored in `nova.s3_images`:

```
mysql> SELECT s3_images.id, s3_images.uuid, images.name FROM nova.s3_images INNER JOIN glance.images ON s3_images.uuid = images.id WHERE images.id = 'd12a9b68-0194-4a88-b5dd-2de711dec05e';
+----+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| id | uuid                                 | name                    |
+----+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| 73 | d12a9b68-0194-4a88-b5dd-2de711dec05e | coreos-stable-v20150728 |
+----+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```